# Get raw email message from GMAIL, showing emoji entity codes (not pictographs!)

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

How can I get the actual raw text of an email in Gmail?  By default, Gmail translates the emoji/Goomoji codes into pictographs.  I want to see the text codes or unicode -- whatever it is when it is transmitted/reviewed by SMTP.

Is that possible, or can I feed the message file (downloaded as an EML) through a CLI tool or something to decode it?

My goal is to figure out a way to filter on Goomoji/Emojis -- I found an old JS called [SpamZero](https://github.com/spamzero/spamzero) but it doesn't seem to work.  I'm hoping I can fix it.

Comment: Have you tried [tag:gmail-api]?